# How to render a choice field in a template

Tags: forms, templates, symfony, twig

I use Symfony2 and twig as template engine.

In my controller I have the following form:

```
      $usr= $this->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();      
      $associatedmissions = array($usr->getMissions());

      $form = $this->createFormBuilder($product)        
       ->add('mission', 'choice', array(
            'choices'   => $associatedmission,
            'multiple'  =>  false,
            'expanded'  => true, ))
```

But when I call the page, appears an error:

```
Catchable Fatal Error: Object of class Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection could not be 
converted to string in 
C:\BitNami\wampstack-5.4.23-
0\frameworks\symfony\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Translation\
IdentityTranslator.php line 65
```

In the profiler I can see the error:

```
CRITICAL - Uncaught PHP Exception Twig_Error_Runtime: "An exception has been thrown 
during the rendering of a template ("") in "form_div_layout.html.twig" at line 99." at 
C:\BitNami\wampstack-5.4.23-0\frameworks\symfony\app\cache\dev\classes.php line 4372 

Context: {"exception":"Object(Twig_Error_Runtime)"}
```

What happened?

It's strange because with it works properly

```
->add('mission', 'entity')
```

-UPDATE--

Here my controller:

```
public function createAction(Request $request)
   {                                           
       $product = new Product();

       $usr= $this->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();      
       $associatedmissions = array($usr->getMissions());

          $form = $this->createFormBuilder($product)                                      
           ->add('name', 'text')
           ->add('mission', 'choice', array(
                'choices'   => $associatedmissions,
                'multiple'  =>  false,
                'expanded'  => false, ))

           ->add('save', 'submit')
           ->getForm();    


       $form->handleRequest($request);
       if ($form->isValid()) {

         $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();    
         $em->persist($product);
         $em->flush();

       return $this->render('AcmeGroundStationBundle:Product:tasksuccess.html.twig', array('product' => $product));
       }    

       return $this->render('AcmeGroundStationBundle:Product:formupload.html.twig', array(
       'form' => $form->createView()
       ));
}
```

Comment: And how are you rendering it field in `twig`?

Comment: @Victor Now with just        `{{ form_start(form) }}        {{ form_end(form) }}`

Comment: Do you pass `form` variable like `$form->createView()` to twig in ` return `$this->render()` method?

Comment: @Victor changed the answer with the controller.

Comment: Hi again, @Gianni :)
Please let me know if Mission class has __toString() method

Comment: @WebHQ I'm your nightmare! ;) Yes, It has __toString() method

Comment: @GianniAlessandro and why you use 'choice' type and not 'entity' when selecting objects?

Comment: @WebHQ Because I don't want to take the data from the repository, but from the $associatedmissions array. Or could I do the query for $associatedmissions inside of the form?

Comment: @GianniAlessandro Ok, I get it - it comes from User object.
$usr->getMissions() returns ArrayCollection?

Comment: @WebHQ How can I check this? I think it works, just because I don't get error, and [the documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#fetching-related-objects) is in the same way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

aYou have this in your controller:

```
$usr= $this->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();      
$associatedmissions = array($usr->getMissions());
```

`$usr->getMissions()` is returning ArrayCollection (based on relations in your Entity). This way `$associatedmissions` is an array with one element - [1] = ArrayCollection of related Mission Objects.

In my opinion you must add to your User entity method:

```
public function getMissionsArray()
{
    $missionArray = array();

    foreach ($this->missions as $key => $val)
    {
        $missionArray[$key] = $val->__toString();
    }
    return $missionArray;
}
```

And use array as choices param in your createFormBuilder statement.

When you validate your Form you have to create Mission object for every selection before persist product.

```
$this->getDoctrine()
            ->getRepository('AcmeGroundStationBundle:Mission')
            ->find($product->mission);
```

**EDIT**

```
// User Entity
// add this function - will return array of ( id => mission.name, )
public function getMissionsArray()
{
    $missionArray = array();

    foreach ($this->missions as $key => $val)
    {
                                // change this to whatever human readable getter
        $missionArray[$key] = $val->__toString();
    }
    return $missionArray;
}

// Controller    
public function createAction(Request $request)
   {                                           
       $product = new Product();

       $usr= $this->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();      
       $associatedmissions = $usr->getMissionsArray();

          $form = $this->createFormBuilder($product)                                      
           ->add('name', 'text')
           ->add('mission', 'choice', array(
                'choices'   => $associatedmissions,
                'multiple'  =>  false,
                'expanded'  => false, ))

           ->add('save', 'submit')
           ->getForm();    


       $form->handleRequest($request);
       if ($form->isValid()) {

         // save selected array item as a Mission object related to Product
         $product->setMission($this->getDoctrine()
            // check if Mission Entity is placed in good bundle ;)
            ->getRepository('AcmeGroundStationBundle:Mission')
            ->find($form->get('mission')->getData()));

         $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();    
         $em->persist($product);
         $em->flush();

       return $this->render('AcmeGroundStationBundle:Product:tasksuccess.html.twig', array('product' => $product));
       }    

       return $this->render('AcmeGroundStationBundle:Product:formupload.html.twig', array(
       'form' => $form->createView()
       ));
}
```

Good Luck!

Comment: thank you as always for your readiness and availability. I didn't understand how to modify my controller.  I also got the error: `Cannot access private property Acme\GroundStationBundle\Entity\Product::$mission`

Comment: Update. With: 
           $associatedmissions= $this->getDoctrine()
            ->getRepository('AcmeManagementBundle:Mission')
            ->findAll($product->mission);
Again I get all the missions, and not only the ones associated.

Comment: Finally the form works. Thanks a lot. Only when I save the object I obtain: `spl_object_hash() expects parameter 1 to be object, integer given`

Comment: This error is probably from wrong form data fetch, I gave you. I'm sorry. Change `$product->setMission()` command and use `$form->get('mission')->getData()` as a `->find()` param.
Answer edited.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use redirect. Is it work?

```
   if ($form->isValid()) {

       $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();    
       $em->persist($product);
       $em->flush();

       return $this->redirect($this->generatePath('current_route_name'));
   }

   return $this->render('AcmeGroundStationBundle:Product:formupload.html.twig', array(
       'form' => $form->createView()
   ));
```

Where `current_route_name` is replace by your route name of current page.

Comment: nothing change. Actually I also tried to replace the second `render` with a redirect, but I obtain `Error: Call to undefined method: generatePath`
With `generateURL` I obtain `La pagina web ha generato un loop di reindirizzamento` (there is a loop in the redirecting)

Comment: Are you extends a base Symfony `Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller` in your controller class?

Comment: Yes, I do! use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

Comment: Are you redefine standart Symfony template of field rendering?

Comment: I didn't redefine nothing. Actually I use FosUserBundle and PugxMultiUserBundle, don't know if this implies something.